# Is it safe to use `instanceOf` when the Error is used and defined in different libraries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, instanceof

Given say three libraries, where library A defines a new error:

```js
class CustomError extends Error { }
```

and library B and C imports and throws this error, is it safe for my project to use `instanceof` to check for this error? E.g.

```js
const { CustomError } = require('@so/errors');
const doSomething = require('@so/doSomething');   // imports `CustomError` from `@so/errors`
const doSomething2 = require('@so/doSomething2'); // imports `CustomError` from `@so/errors`

try {
  doSomething();  // can throw `CustomError`
  doSomething2(); // can throw `CustomError`
} catch (err) {
  // is this check reliable?
  if(err instanceof CustomError) {
    console.log('caught!');
  }

  throw err;
}
```

Or does it depend on `npm` to symlink both `@so/doSomething` and `@so/doSomething2` to the same `@so/errors` package I am using? If so, does that mean `@so/errors` has to be at the same version that `@so/doSomething` and `@so/doSomething2` depends on?

Comment: I'd say it's pretty hacky to do that. Would be better if B and C exported the class